# Serialize an array of arrays as a single XML element

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a field:

```
public Field[][] fields;
```

And I want an XML:

```
<Fields>
    <Field x="0" y="0">
       ...
    </Field>
    <Field x="0" y="1">
       ...
    </Field>
    ...
</Fields>
```

Unfortunately, C# XmlSerializer gives me

```
<Fields>
    <ArrayOfField>
        .... some fields here
    </ArrayOfField>
    <ArrayOfField>
       .... some here
    </ArrayOfField>
            ...
</Fields>
```

How do I achieve this?

Well, actually I don't need to stick to an array of arrays. The fields do represent a 2D space, so it was a natural choice. Would a `Dictionary` serialize the way I need?

Comment: could you tell us where this x and y attributes are populated. you could transform your xml using xslt transform

Comment: I didnt give all the details, x and y are public fields of `Field` class and are mapped to the attributes. The `Field` class serializes okay. I just cant find a way to serialize a 2d array, neither multi-dim, array of arrays nor jagged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a property that converts between the array of arrays and a single array:

```
using System.Linq;

...

[XmlIgnore]
public Field[][] Fields;

[XmlArray("Fields")]
public Field[] SerializedFields
{
    get
    {
        return this.Fields.SelectMany(fields => fields).ToArray();
    }
    set
    {
        this.Fields = new Field[value.Max(field => field.x) + 1][];
        for (int x = 0; x < this.Fields.Length; x++)
        {
            this.Fields[x] = value.Where(field => field.x == x).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about this, but how would you deserialize it ..?

Comment: See my updated answer. It assumes several things: the `x` and `y` properties match the array indexes; there may be gaps in `x`; for a given `x`, there are no gaps in `y` (that is, if `Fields[9][3]` exists, so do `Fields[9][0]`, `Fields[9][1]`, and `Fields[9][2]`); it is OK to drop unused elements at the end of each array.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to implement the IXmlSerializable interface: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx

You can then specify in your `WriteXml()` method how the xml should be written (formatted).